# install.package() on RStudio on Amazon EC2 doesn't work. Package not available for R version 3.3.3

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio

I've seen this: [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

and been through the list. No luck. I've also navigated via SSH to my library to see if there was some LOCK file or corrupt install. There is nothing there.

I literally just installed RStudio on Amazon EC2 and can't install the any new packages. 
I've done it this way: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-aws/
I've also used Ubuntu with Louis Anslett's AMI: http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/

I get the same problem in both. I have downloaded them manually and installed the tar.gz files from the temp directory. The CRAN repository seems to be fine because install.packages() downloads the tar.gz to /tmp/Rtmp2Rh9Zr/downloaded_packages/ just fine, but then the actual install process fails.

When I run install.packages("haven") for instance, it says

```
> install.packages("haven")
Installing package into ‘/home/jblocher/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘R6’, ‘assertthat’, ‘rlang’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘readr’, ‘hms’, ‘tibble’, ‘BH’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/R6_2.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 325641 bytes (318 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 318 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/assertthat_0.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 11612 bytes (11 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 11 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_0.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 201419 bytes (196 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 196 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.12.11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2485092 bytes (2.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.4 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/readr_1.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 233793 bytes (228 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 228 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/hms_0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7271 bytes
==================================================
downloaded 7271 bytes

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tibble_1.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 91235 bytes (89 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 89 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/BH_1.62.0-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 10181096 bytes (9.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 9.7 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/haven_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 150016 bytes (146 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 146 KB

Error in library(haven) : there is no package called ‘haven’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘R6’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(haven) : there is no package called ‘haven’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘assertthat’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(haven) : there is no package called ‘haven’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(haven) : there is no package called ‘haven’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(haven) : there is no package called ‘haven’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(haven) : there is no package called ‘haven’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘BH’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(haven) : there is no package called ‘haven’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(haven) : there is no package called ‘haven’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘readr’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(haven) : there is no package called ‘haven’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘haven’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpia0VEs/downloaded_packages’
```

When I install it using the already downloaded package, it says

```
> install.packages("/tmp/Rtmp2Rh9Zr/downloaded_packages/haven_1.0.0.tar.gz")
Installing package into ‘/home/jblocher/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘/tmp/Rtmp2Rh9Zr/downloaded_packages/haven_1.0.0.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3)
```

Comment: No packages? haven is an example. I can't get any new packages to load.

Comment: My bad. missed part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing an archive file to `install.packages` you may need to specify `repos=NULL`:

```
install.packages("/tmp/Rtmp2Rh9Zr/downloaded_packages/haven_1.0.0.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

On my EC2 instance, I ran into the same problems when trying to install packages on RStudio, e.g., car, that involve RAM-intensive compilations. This could be fixed by adding swap space as described here

http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2015/06/amazon-ec2-adding-swap/

Comment: While this may answer the question, 
[it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the 
essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.